# Regex for specific pattern containing multiline text

Tags: regex

Need help in creating Regex for below -

Input -

```
Steps_taken "" loop
{
_1 "1st"
[
Sub cat = "_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7"
],
_2 "2nd"
[
Sub cat = "_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_98"
]
} fields -
(
slice "What were the steps you have taken from the time when the symptom appeared to when the pain         was addressed?

categorical [1…1]

fix exclusive
} ran;

) expand grid;
```

Output -

slice "What were the steps you have taken from the time when the symptom appeared to when the pain         was addressed?

```
categorical [1…1]

fix exclusive
} ran;
```

There can be multiple instances of such pattern in a text file.

In Summary, I need to delete 2 parts here -

```
From the beginning of the line containing keyword 'loop' till keyword 'fields -'
Opening bracket (which will always be there below the line containing 'fields -') and closing bracket (which will always contain keyword 'grid;')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your summary of what should happen, and your output (for given input) example do not match. I assume your summary is what you want.

You can use a regex with replace:

```
/[^\n\r]+loop[\s\S]*?fields[ \-\n\r\(]*([\s\S]*?)\) expand grid;[\n\r]+/g
```

Explanation:

- `[^\n\r]+loop` - scan over `loop` line
- `[\s\S]*?fields` - non-greedily scan over anything until `fields`
- `[ \-\n\r\(]*` - scan over additional characters we don't want
- `([\s\S]*?)` - non-greedily scan over and capture anything...
- `\) expand grid;` - ...until `) expand grid;`
- `[\n\r]+` - scan over newlines
- the `g` flag is for global, e.g. match multiple patterns like this
- for replace, reference the capture group with `$` or `\1`, depending on your language

Let me use JavaScript with two repeating patterns to demo here on stackoverlow, you can easily translate that to your language:

```js
const input = `Steps_taken "" loop
{
_1 "1st"
[
Sub cat = "_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7"
],
_2 "2nd"
[
Sub cat = "_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_98"
]
} fields -
(
slice "What were the steps of example 1?"
categorical [1…1]
fix exclusive
} ran;
) expand grid;
Steps_taken "" loop
{
_1 "1st"
[
Sub cat = "_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7"
],
_2 "2nd"
[
Sub cat = "_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_98"
]
} fields -
(
slice "What were the steps of example 2?"
categorical [2…2]
fix exclusive
} ran;
) expand grid;
`;

const regex = /[^\n\r]+loop[\s\S]*?fields[ \-\n\r\(]*([\s\S]*?)\) expand grid;[\n\r]+/g;
var result = input.replace(regex, '$1');
console.log('result:\n' + result);
```

Output:

```
result:
slice "What were the steps of example 1?"
categorical [1…1]
fix exclusive
} ran;
slice "What were the steps of example 2?"
categorical [2…2]
fix exclusive
} ran;
```

Comment: Thanks for you response Peter. I just realized that while posting it looks like some of my content got misplaced, hence the confusion.
Basically the need is -
I need to remove the entire content from the beginning of the line containing keyword 'loop', till fields - and the brackets '()' which starts from the line below the one that contains keyword 'fields -' and end point of bracket closure will always contain the keyword 'grid;' (Text in-between brackets needs to be there as it is).

Comment: Unless I miss something that's how my regex works.

Comment: Thanks a ton for providing the regex for me. Just another query here - For the later part of my regex if I would like to select the line which begins with keyword 'grid;' instead of '\) expand grid;' I can put '[^\n\r]+grid;' - Is this understanding correct?

Comment: On your new question, I am not clear where the closing parenthesis is, on previous line? Not existing? If not existing, your regex is `/[^\n\r]+loop[\s\S]*?fields[ \-\n\r\(]*([\s\S]*?)[\n\r]+grid;[\n\r]+/g`

Comment: [^\n\r]+loop[\s\S]*?fields[ \-\n\r\(]*([\s\S]*?)\) expand grid;[\n\r]+
- With the above pattern, it is working partially-
After deleting till 'fields -' , it should only delete 2 more lines -
a) Start of bracket '(' which will always be the next line of keyword 'fields -'
b) Line containing the closure bracket ')' which will always contain the keyword 'grid;'

With above regex,it is working till delete 'fields -' part but after that instead of only deleting 2 lines which contains the brackets, it is also removing the text in-between the brackets. Hope,i am able to explain clearly now:-)

Comment: In this case it must be difference betwen the JavaScript regex, and the uipath regex engine. If you run above code snippet, you will see that it works as expected. What regex flavor does uipath use?